# How do we assign value for ng-model dynamically through a template url?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular js.I have written a directive to load the template url and tried changing the ng-model value. But the value doesnt change.

I tried simulating this exmaple http://tinyurl.com/hg7ehge
except that I was trying to load the html from url.

Following is the plunker code: http://tinyurl.com/zwmleec

Answer (score 1):

To refere model by dynamic name you can isolate scope (scope: true) and use `$parent` reference to outer scope:

```
.directive('dynamicmodel', function($templateRequest, $compile) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.name = attrs.comm;
            $templateRequest("template.html").then(function(html) {
                element.replaceWith($compile(html)(scope));
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and then in template use `scope.comm`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent[name].subject" />
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/B4HgvxuT1jZJ2H3U9UO9?p=info

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The solution I was looking for is , where in I can generate the ng-model value dynamically. So when I used the directive 'dynamicmodel', and pass the value as email from the input, the value for  the ngmodel of the input in the template should be generated as 'email.subject' .If I change the  '<dynamicmodel comm="email"></dynamicmodel>' to ' <dynamicmodel comm="sms"></dynamicmodel>' the value of ng model in the template should change to "sms.subject"

Comment: Oh, I missunderstood. Check updated answer and demo.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked. But I am stuck at the next level. When I try to use the defined model in the controller, it says "email.subject" is undefined. I undertstand that the controller is getting loaded before the view is rendered. Is there a way to load the controller once the directive template has been rendered. I tried using the '$viewContentloaded" but it didnt work. Any ideas here?